# Maximum likelihood estimation for Cauchy noise

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, covariance, cauchy-distribution

What is the maximum likelihood estimator of the covariance matrix for a given vector in the presence of Cauchy noise?

How can we calculate it given that the Cauchy distribution has infinite variance?

Comment: How do you define a multivariate Cauchy distribution? Do you mean a special multivariate t? In which case the scale matrix is well-defined if not necessarily a covariance matrix.

Comment: How does your question differ from [that one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125381/7224)?

Comment: I am not using multivariate Cauchy distribution. I am using standard  Cauchy Distribution.

Comment: The multivariate Cauchy is a special case of the multivariate ***t*** with one degree of freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Nadarajah and Kotz (2007)](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bemis/MFM/workshop/2010/estimating_multivariate_t.pdf), given the log-likelihood function of the multivariate ***t*** distribution with parameters $(μ,R,ν)$,
$$L(μ,R,ν)=−\frac{n}{2}\log|R|−\frac{ν+p}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(ν+s_i)\,,$$
the maximum likelihood estimator can be found by an EM algorithm exploiting the latent Gaussian representation of the ***t***.

The EM iteration is of the form
$$μ^{(m+1)}=\text{average}(w^{(m)}_ix_i)\big/\text{average}(w^{(m)}_i)$$
and
$$R^{(m+1)}=\text{average}(w^{(m)}_i\{x_i-μ^{(m+1)}\}\{x_i-μ^{(m+1)}\}^\text{T})\big/\text{average}(w^{(m)}_i)$$
where
$$w^{(m)}_i=(ν+p)\big/\{\nu+(x_i−μ^{(m)})(^\text{T}R^{(m)})^{-1}(x_i−μ^{(m)})\}$$

Comment: Thanks but as this is for multivariate  t distribution as I need for cauchy me degree of freedom will be 1. We will get MLE of multivariate Cauchy.

Comment: Okay what will be our first assumption to start iteration.

Comment: Have you checked the basics of [the EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)? The starting point only matters in determining the limiting value of the algorithm and should thus be modified for multiple runs of EM.

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the distribution of the ML covariance matrix for a Cauchy noise?

Comment: Sorry sir, your answers are really helping me to learn, I am new to use stack exchange and a new learner may be due to this I missed but I found most of your answers useful.